# React: how to add a props to a component inside a library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm using a component [someone else wrote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search) called react-search in the following way...

```
  <div>
    <Search items={ITEMS} />
  </div>
```

This creates an `<input>` inside a `<div>` inside a `<div>`. I need to add the prop `onKeyDown={ this.myMethod }` to the `<input>`. What is the best way to achieve this? I have a feeling that editing the code inside node_modules is not the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the library specifically provides a way to pass props into its components' children, there is no other way to do it. React components are a bit "opaque" by design so that you can't futz around with their internal state and children. So in this case you actually *do* have to edit the library's code to accommodate this.

However that is not such an intimidating thing to do. Just pass your event handler to the library's component as a prop, and then in the library find where the `<input>` element is being rendered and give it the event handler as usual. I've had to edit many a React library in similar ways, and it's totally fine to do.

Edit: Actually I should add that you can just bypass React and add an event handler directly to the `input` element using plain JavaScript. For example, in the library component's parent's `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` functions you would add and remove the event handler, respectively, using `addEventListener` or similar. However it's *generally* a bad idea to hack together work-arounds to React's own functionality when you can do the same thing inside of React with a bit more work. It could also be fairly difficult to identify exactly which `input` element you want to add listeners to.

Answer (score 0):

The library [only accepts the `onKeyChange` prop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search#onkeychange-optional). If you want the onKeyDown event you would have to edit the library on your own or [send in a PR to the code base](https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-search).